# Overlapping with Admob and Webview

Tags: android, xml, webview, admob

For the first time I'm developing an Android application and so far it's going really well except for one thing. I made a webview layout and I wanted to show ads in the app. So I added the AdMob ads and they're working really well. But there's one problem.

The AdMob covers a part of the WebView, so it's not shifting the WebView layout up but it's covering it. And that's annoying because you can't read a part of the webview's text. How can I fix it?

This is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayout01"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white">  
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
    </ScrollView>   
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="helloworldcode"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER" />
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to give the ScrollView an `android:layout_above="@+id/ad_layout"` but then my app force closes... So I really hope somebody can help me as I'm looking for it now for hours :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Comment: What's the stacktrace you're getting in your logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `layout_above` should work, but if this is really your complete layout, the easiest way in my opinion is to replace the `RelativeLayout` with a `LinearLayout` since you're only laying out those views in a line anyway and then give the main part a weight. I'd probably also get rid of the `ScrollView` and just let the `WebView` scroll itself, but:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayout01"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
    </ScrollView>   
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="helloworldcode"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />
</LinearLayout>
```